# Javascript variables and parameters

Tags: javascript

I have a question as to why this is not working. Noob question, probably.

```
var itemCheck = {
    darkBerries: 0
}

var id = darkBerries;

itemcheck . id ++;
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happens instead of working?  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is your desired output?

Comment: `itemcheck` is not defined. `itemCheck` is a different variable. `darkBerries` is not defined. Read about [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to increment the `darkBerries` property using the `id` variable. To do that you have to save a string in the `id` and use the brackets notation to access the object's property:

```
var itemCheck = {
    darkBerries: 0
};

var id = "darkBeries";
itemCheck[id]++;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemCheck = {
    darkBerries: 0
}

var id = itemCheck.darkBerries;

id ++;
```